# Annoying "please wait" screen every second time PC is booted

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot

So, I uninstalled Ubuntu from my previously dual boot machine and it uninstalled fine, except for two things:

1. There's still a 512 MB EFI partition on the D drive I had Ubuntu on;
2. Sometimes [specifically: every second time] I get a "Please Wait" screen, then boot repair (Continue/Boot options blue screen, IDK what it's called), I choose continue and the system boots normally.

[Partitions are arranged as in this image. Partitions once used by Linux highlighted in yellow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRj7h.png)

Comment: Can you please be more specific in what you actually want an answer for? Please edit and clarify what question you have.

Comment: The EFI partition is required for booting Windows and it's not a leftover.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Isn't the EFI partition used to boot Windows on the C drive? The D drive seems to be a leftover from the previous Linux installation.

Comment: @VarunNarravula I don't want to get a please wait screen every second time I boot up my computer.

Comment: @SlayerGames44 It depends on the order of the drives.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia i don't know how to explain this exactly, so could you please look at the image I sent as a link?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "please wait" message is coming from GRUB bootloader that was installed along with Ubuntu. But when you uninstalled Ubuntu, the Grub remained.

There are different [ways](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1396560) on how to recover from this situation, but some people report that if you run

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

from Windows command prompt then windows will boot directly.

Comment: It's a Windows "please wait" message. I've also noticed that it only appears when I force-turn off the computer, if I turn it off using the start menu, nothing happens.